# How to determine the output value to inscribe an Ordinal?

Tags: ordinals

[image]

It's only mentioned the fee to inscribe the Ordinal.
But how about the output value?
For BRC-20, the suggested value in UniSat is 546.
For Ordinals, it's varied.
Most of the Ordinals collection like Bitcoin Punks, Bitcoin Frogs using 10,000 sats.
Others more or less than 10k.

I'm able to use 1 sats for 330kb image on testnet.
What's the downside?